# Python OpenCV - Webcam capture returns blank screen

Tags: python, opencv

Im using pycharm to run the following code.But Im getting a black screen with no output.
cv2 version - 4.0.0 (intall by pycharm installer)
Python - 3.6
windows 10 64bit

```
   import cv2

   print(cv2.__version__)
   video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


   while (video_capture.isOpened()):
      ret, frame = video_capture.read()
      if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('win', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
      print(frame)
```

I just printed the frame and I got following output with lot of zeros. Note that I have used the same webcam in same machine with Opencv and Java and it works fine.

```
[[[ 80   1   9]
  [114 120   1]
  [  0   0 176]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]
```

[Please see the blank output screenshot hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltUmG.png)

Comment: Can you try  `video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`

Comment: Your code seems OK, you should restart the IDE and run again.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issues, It was my Kaspersky Virus scanner which was blocking it. This is really strange since it light up the Webcam so I never thought it was blocked. Once I disabled virus scanner it worked like a charm